# how can i merge multiple files in linux?

Tags: unix, merge, cat

I have 30 different length files, each of which start with 1 and ends by around 2000. I can join them by using "cat" options in unix but I want to join those files sequentially. Here is the picture of files:

**File:1**

1 T=   295. E= -.72913162E+03
..
..

1821 T=   314. E= -.72917614E+03

**File:2**

1 T=   326. E= -.72917628E+03
..
..

1834 T=   318. E= -.72917464E+03.

I want like this,

**NEW FILE**

1 T=   295. E= -.72913162E+03
..
..

1821 T=   314. E= -.72917614E+03

**1822** T=   326. E= -.72917628E+03
..
..

3655 T=   318. E= -.72917464E+03

Comment: Not clear what you really need. You have two lines headed with "1", what about them in the "new file"? I can see only one...

Comment: Thanks for your time. Yeap, in the new file only one "1" (which is coming from file:1) and the second "1" (from file:2) changes to "1822" **which is the next number of file:1 last entiity 1821.**

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand all your constraints, but how about just stripping off the numbers and renumbering from scratch, eg

```
cat * | sed 's/ *[0-9]* //' | nl
```

Comment: @Sushanta Great!  How about accepting my answer as correct then? :)